# webpack and two different origin websites

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack. I have two projects. one for front-end. one for back-end. back-end is also on javascript. So I bundle the back-end with webpack.

The files I get after bundling back-end is:

1. `main.js`
2. `test1.js`
3. `test2.js`
4. `test1~test2.js`

`test1`, `test2` and `test1~test2.js` files are on-demand chunk files.

Now, I am entering the url of the front-end website, (url is `front-end.website.com/test1`), when that happens, I am downloading `main.js` and `test1.js` immediatelly.  After that, There's a button on which I should click and after clicking, `axios` should make the request to fetch `test1~test2.js`. As you see and as I said, `test1~test2.js` should be loaded lazily and that's what happens, but.....

**The problem:** When the request for `test1~test2.js` happens, the request doesn't get made to back-end origin, but for the front-end origin and this causes the file not to be loaded as this file doesn't exist on front-end. Looks like in `main.js` , there's a lazy loaded code for `test1~test2.js` but it doesn't have the whole origin path and when front-end tries to load it, it thinks that it should load from itself.

How can I fix that?

**The workarounds** (but i hate this) : I tried to use publicPath in my back-end's webpack config such as: https://back-end.website.com, but what this causes is that when requests get made to back-end, doens't matter for which file, the actual url for the request becomes https://back-end.website.com/http://back-end.website.com/file (something like that).

Comment: why does the backend need bundling? It runs on a single, or low number of, server(s), each of which only has to load all its files once. This is completely unlike the client-side code, which has to get loaded as many times as people open pages on your site.

Comment: it's not an actual back-end. it's just a javascript app. pure js . some kind of 3rd-party thing.

Comment: it either runs on a server, where it's back-end code, or it runs on the client's browser, and then it's front-end code. Even if it does database management and the like, running it on the user's computer, in their browser, means it's front-end code So making sure you're using the right terms in your post is important.

Comment: yeah, so it looks like it's front-end then. Any idea how to achieve what I want?

Comment: it sounds like you just want two separate webpack tasks, which is a pretty standard way to build multiple bundles.

Comment: I have two seperate projects/two separate webpack configs. the issue is that when getting file from one project into another via axios, and then that file also asks another file from that other project, that another file gets requested from the first project, not from another. makes sense?

Comment: It makes more sense now, but notice that you're suddenly talking about axios, which you mention nowhere in your post, nor in your tags. So it's worth updating your post to explain your setup a bit more based on this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208867/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: Can you explain the need for axios in order to fetch the back-end?

Comment: The four files you mention are frontend files right? Then why not host all of them on the same web server?

Comment: Show some code example, front and back. That would help a lot

Comment: How does the front-end know which files it needs to download when clicking the button, considering these chunks are created by a separate and unrelated backend configuration?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very unusual setup and not ordinary code-splitting. The files generated by the backend seem to be the response of an XHR (axios or otherwise), while the implementation you are trying to do looks like code-splitting.

If the files are fetched by `axios` as you indicate, then you can add the backend URL to the axios request

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://back-end.website/',
});
```

The front-end files wouldn't be fetched by axios. In the unlikely scenario that they are, create two axios instances.